# regression using Data Analysis toolpack throwing up errors [Excel]

Tags: excel, statistics, regression, data-analysis

I have a table as follows. I'm trying to use the regression feature to get an equation for the data.
[image: My table]

Here are my inputs for the regression:

[image: my inputs]

But I get the following error when hitting OK:

[image: my error]

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Can you say what version of Excel you are using (and toolpak if possible) plz? I'm using Excel 365 and I do get an error message, but not the same one.

Answer (score 1):

This is just speculation, but I'm wondering if the error message is misleading? If I try this in Excel 365 I get the following:

[image]

Therefore I try extending the number of rows by 1:

[image]

and get a result, although some stats are missing:

[image]

If I add another row of data, I get all the stats.

So I suggest increasing the number of rows in your data and seeing if it makes any difference.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try updating the Input X any Y ranges? Try following:

Input Y Range: `$B$2:$B$4`

Input X Range: `$C$2:$E$4`

As per your screen grab current range includes the column header which is a string and might be the reason for error.

Comment: I've tried this but get the same result, unfortunately!

Answer (score -1):

First of all sample set remains too low. So, the reliability of the analysis will be questionable. And that way you are getting error for value.

Your other problem is row and column value is same row must be greater than column.

And you can execute this analysis in SPSS or another program.
I'm saying again your data isn't enough for this analysis.

BEST REGARDS...